# How to create a scatter plot with linear trend from multiple data sets in an array

Tags: python, dataframe, scatter-plot

I'd like to create a scatter plot with 'age' and 'income' as the x and y axis from this data, whilst also separating by gender (m or f):

```
vals = [[39, 50907.00500830538, 'm'], [71, 58137.09607273632, 'm'], [27, 44311.25956375814, 'f'], [50, 53194.40398297405, 'f'], [41, 48227.6226667045, 'f'], [38, 51081.77610221989, 'f'], [25, 49202.743772155154, 'f'], [45, 46958.227355122865, 'm'], [46, 54815.07514726054, 'm'], [25, 46734.0863416376, 'f'], [44, 52252.36769285552, 'm'], [70, 58453.80544624214, 'f']]
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
ages = [x[0] for x in vals]
incomes = [x[1] for x in vals]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

male_data = [(a,i) for a,i,g in vals if g == 'male']
male_ages = [a for a,i in male_data]
male_incomes = [i for a,i in male_data]
ax.scatter(male_ages, male_incomes, color='blue', label='male')

female_data = [(a,i) for a,i,g in vals if g == 'female']
female_ages = [a for a,i in female_data]
female_incomes = [i for a,i in female_data]
ax.scatter(female_ages, female_incomes, color='red', label='female')

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel('age')
ax.set_ylabel('income')
```

I'm also trying to use this code to create a linear trend however I was unsuccessful:

```
p = np.poly1d(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were checking for the wrong string. The data labeled it as "f" or "m" and you were checking for the full word.

```
female_data = [(a,i) for a,i,g in vals if g == 'f']

male_data = [(a,i) for a,i,g in vals if g == 'm']
```

```
#substitute in ages and incomes for x and y respectively. 
#Z returns a the coefficients starting from higher power to 0, in this case from 1 to 0.

z = np.polyfit(ages, incomes, 1) 

#compose the function 
f = lambda x: (x * z[0]) + z[1] 

#create the range of x for our graph
x = [x for x in np.linspace(20,80,10)]
#use our function to calculate the y for each x in our range
y = [f(a) for a in x]

#plot the line
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.set_xlabel('age')
ax.set_ylabel('income')

plt.show()
```